# how to get selectedvalue from DataGridViewComboBoxColumn?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

i have a datagridview which has a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn for unit i want to get the selectedvalue of each DataGridViewComboBoxColumn how could i get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this -

```
dataGridView1.Rows["YourRowNumber"].Cells["YourColumnNameOrNumber"].Value;
```

Comment: by using this i am getting the text here not the value. i want to get the value 
instead i used this now it is working fine  
dataGridView1.Rows["YourRowNumber"].Cells["YourColumnNameOrNumber"].Value

Comment: @NIGHIL DAS - So it is working fine now right? Have edited my answer to reflect correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looping through the grid then you should be interested in getting the FormattedValue of the Combobox cell since that would be actual persisted value of the selected combobox item

```
dataGridView1[colIndex,rowIndx].FormattedValue
```

Answer (score 0):

dataGridView1.Rows["RowNumber"].Cells["ColumnNameOrNumber"].**Value** *will return value of DataGridViewComboBoxColumn* but dataGridView1.Rows["RowNumber"].Cells["ColumnNameOrNumber"].**FormattedValue** *will return Displaying text of DataGridViewComboBoxColumn* ...

It is useful when our displaying text is different from value we are setting ...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.formattedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Cheers!