# Why on Initial load DataGridViewComboBoxColumn showing empty value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Hi all I have binded my datagridview with DataGridViewComboBoxColumn as follows

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn clnStatus = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
clnStatus.DataPropertyName = "Status";
clnStatus.AutoComplete = true;
clnStatus.ValueMember = "absent";
clnStatus.Name = "Absent - Leave - Present";
clnStatus.DataSource = new string[] { "absent", "present", "leave" };
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, clnStatus);
```

But this is resulting in an empty value for my datagridview as follows. What should I do inorder to get the one value selected

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no initial value selected as you don't have any value for the `Value` property of the cell, hence you would need to set that value by looping through the grid.

```
(row.Cells[1] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Value =(row.Cells[1] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items[yourneededindex]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following line of code to set the value:

```
dataGridView1.Rows["RowNumber"].Cells["ColumnNameOrNumber"].Value;
```

Reference: [how to get selectedvalue from DataGridViewComboBoxColumn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732263/how-to-get-selectedvalue-from-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn)

Answer (score 0):

The Value property has no effects on form load. Instead of use static ComboBox items, try to bind the combo with your datatable source and set the following property:

```
comboBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "Column_Name";
```

Then use the .Value on each cell to be sure every row has the expected value.