# How load specific value DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Hi all I have binded my datagridview with DataGridViewComboBoxColumn as follows
            dataGridView1.DataSource = db.DT(sql);

```
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Column1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        Column1.HeaderText = "Status";

        Column1.Name = "Column1";
        DTchequeStatus = db.DT("SELECT [ID] ,[Status] FROM [ChequeStatus]");

        Column1.DisplayMember = "Status";
        Column1.ValueMember = "ID";
        Column1.DataSource = DTchequeStatus;



        foreach (DataRow DR in DTchequeStatus.Rows)
        {

           // Column1.Items.Add(DR["Status"].ToString());
        }
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Column1);



         dataGridView1.Columns["Column1"].ReadOnly = false;
         foreach (DataGridViewRow DR in dataGridView1.Rows)
         {
             (DR.Cells["Column1"] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Value = (int)DR.Cells["Cheque Status"].Value;
         }
```

But this is resulting in an empty value for my datagridview as follows. What should I do inorder to get the one value selected[image]  [i tried  this Why on Initial load DataGridViewComboBoxColumn showing empty value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669974/why-on-initial-load-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-showing-empty-value)   but doesn't works

Comment: You forget to set `Column1.DataPropertyName="SomeField"`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei  `Column1.DataPropertyName = "Status";` set but doesn't work

Comment: Does't work is not a suitable problem description. What happened after setting `Column1.DataPropertyName = "Status";`? Does `Status` column belongs to the table which is `DataSource` of your `DataGridView`?

Comment: Thanks i set to  `Column1.DataPropertyName = "ID";` now it working,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just setting

```
Column1.DataPropertyName = "ID"
```

will resolved the problem