# Get Selected index and Selected item from DataGridViewComboBoxCell in unbound column

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a big problem that make me so confuse that I have a DataGridView without using binding which has DataGridViewComboBoxColumn (unbound column) and I want to get selected index or selected item in the ComBoBoxCell (my item i custom item).

I try to cast or follow this website (http://satishjdotnet.blogspot.com/2009/05/getting-selected-value-of-combo-box-in.html) but I only recieve Error:

> "Value is not invalid"

. So how can I solve it?
Please help me. Thanks a lot.
Here is my custom Item in combobox:

```
public class CustomItem {
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() {
        return Text;
    }
    public CustomItem(string text, object value) {
        this.Text = text;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

and how I add it to DataGridViewComboBoxColumn:

```
List<CustomItem> teamItem = new List<CustomItem>();
teamItem.Add(new CustomItem(this._homeTeam["Name"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(this._homeTeam["Id"])));
teamItem.Add(new CustomItem(this._awayTeam["Name"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(this._awayTeam["Id"])));
foreach (CustomItem i in teamItem) {
    ((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)this.dataGridViewGoalInformation.Columns["Team"]).Items.Add(i);
}
```

Comment: DataGridViewComboBoxCell c = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
    c = DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells("MyColumnName");
    c.Items.Add("Item1")

Comment: @CarlProthman I want to get selected index or selected item in my combobox cell as I said. and I showed my CustomItem in code too. DO you have any Idea for me ?

Comment: Sorry, misread your question.  Take a look at this answer... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732263/how-to-get-selectedvalue-from-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

Comment: but what event in datagridview must I catch ?

Comment: You could access it during a button on-click occurs (e.g SaveButton). Then access the control's selected value.

Comment: I've just done it but I still get error "Value is not invalid"
        private void dataGridViewGoalInformation_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            CustomItem item = this.dataGridViewGoalInformation.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Team"].Value as CustomItem;
            MessageBox.Show(item.Text);
        }

Comment: What code are you using to access the control's value?

Comment: I have just posted it. I used CellContentClick event

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get DatagridviewComboBoxCell's SelectedIndex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157239/get-datagridviewcomboboxcells-selectedindex)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the CustomItem class, with the Value as an **int**

```
 public class CustomItem
 {
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }

    public CustomItem(string text, int value)
    {
        this.Text = text;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

To get the value, make sure to hook up the event: EditingControlShowing

```
dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing;
```

Then to get the value out of the combobox when it changes: 1) get the combobox control, 2) then get it's selected value:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.Control is ComboBox)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
        comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }
}

private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl dataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
    object value = dataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl.SelectedValue;
    if (value != null)
    {
        int intValue = (int)dataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl.SelectedValue;

        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I was not able to get the selected value with `dataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl.SelectedValue`, but I was able to get the selected value with `dataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl.Items[dataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl.SelectedIndex]`.